# Mysql multiple row index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a following query in mysql.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Accounts AS a
WHERE
    ('s' IS NULL OR (a.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('s','%') OR
                      a.LastName LIKE CONCAT('s','%') OR
                      a.FullName LIKE CONCAT('s','%')
                     )
    )
```

How Should I put indexes for the table?

p.s.
's' is actually a variable in stored proc, so 's' IS NULL and concat are necessary.

Comment: What is 's'?  A text string or another column?

Comment: @Larry Lusting: According to the syntax is a constant literal... I suppose...

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz: That's according to syntax, but then the query makes very little sense. Maybe that's a placeholder for prepared statement in some external script?

Comment: @Mchl: 100% true. But I guessed he/she copy+pasted from his/her code...

Comment: @Pablo, if those are single quotes, you're right.  But the query as written only makes (a little) sense if they should be backtick identifier quotes.

Comment: @aikixd: if you copy+pasted the code, then there are some serious errors on it, since you are probably trying to use `s` as a variable. Does your query work at all?

Comment: You have misunderstood me. I pulled the query out of sp and changed the var to constant for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. <s>`'s' IS NULL` is always false</s>
2. <s>Is there any reason you're using `CONCAT('s','%')` instead of `'s%'`?</s>
3. Try a composite index on `(FirstName, LastName, FullName)`, although it might not work really well for `(VAR)CHAR`s (or even at all it seems)

---

Since #3 didn't work, I can only refer you to MySQL manual now. THere's a bit about using how MySQL uses indexes with LIKE [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I don't think a composite index will help for the whole query since it will only help your `a.FirstName like 's%'` clause...

Comment: 1, 2 It's a part of a procedure, the string is actually a variable. 3. I tried one index for three columns, and multiple indexes for each column, but the optimizer didn't use them

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just a quick suggestion: do not use **concat** if you don't have to. Your query can be rewritten as `('s' is NULL)` is always FALSE so you can will always get all rows based on the second condition anyway:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Accounts AS a
WHERE
    a.FirstName LIKE 's%' OR
    a.LastName LIKE 's%' OR
    a.FullName LIKE 's%'
```

Indexes that **might** help, but no necessarily will are:

```
create index idx_01 on accounts(FirstName);
create index idx_01 on accounts(LastName);
create index idx_01 on accounts(FullName);
```

You can also consider a FULL TEXT SEARCH index for your table.

Answer (score 0):

FOR you `full text indexing` is also an option

add fulltext index for 3 fields then

use

`MATCH() AGAINST()` syntax

Eg

```
 SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
 AGAINST ('superb catch' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I use InnoDB, so I can't use fulltext index

Comment: Another option would be to use Sphinx,